# In Thunderbird, how to make the "get messages" button also update "sent" folders other than inboxes

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

In Thunderbird, by default, the "get messages" button updates all inboxes. How can I make the "get messages" button also updates "sent" folders other than inboxes?

Comment: Doesn't the folder update from the server when you click on the folder?  (It should if it's an imap account)
    Why does a folder other than Inbox need to be checked for new messages?

Comment: @wsmwk You can build "search folders" that include both inbox and sent box. In this case, thunderbird won't retrieve new messages when clicking on the search folder.